# Why My MobaXterm Starting 2 sshd Processes on My Server?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, mobaxterm

When I'm using Windows Terminal or Visual Studio Code, only 1 process of sshd was started. But when using MobaXterm, it seems to start two processes.

When I'm connecting my server with ssh using VS Code or Windows Terminal, and then

```bash
$ netstat -anp | grep [My IP]                                                                                           
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 [Server IP]:22        [My IP]:[Port]     ESTABLISHED -
```

But when I'm using MobaXterm, then

```bash
$ netstat -anp | grep [My IP]                                                                                           
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 [Server IP]:22        [My IP]:[Port]     ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 [Server IP]:22        [My IP]:[Port]     ESTABLISHED -
```

Besides, when disconnected, the two sshd processes will both disappear. Because of my server is a shared server, so occupying 2 connections may be unconvenient to other users because of the MaxStartup limit. It confused me so much and I wonder how I can change some settings in order to disable the duplicated process?

Comment: Stack Overflow is _only_ for questions about writing code -- system administration is outside our scope, and questions on that topic more properly belong on [unix.se].

Comment: That said, just because there are two process table entries doesn't mean those two processes aren't part of the same service; indeed, that's the easiest way to get two services bound to the same address (have one service bound to that address that uses a `fork()` syscall to duplicate itself so it can have two different pieces doing different work concurrently); this kind of thing is also done more transiently in sshd when it creates a copy of itself with fewer privileges, f/e to run sandboxed auth code. You won't see sshd counting these as separate entries against the MaxStartup limit.